# Google search: any way to easily toggle between search in one country and one other?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-search

I need to make many searches, and for each search I first need to restrict my searches to USA (where I am now), then to Italy.  I know both Italian and English very well. [Google preferences](http://www.google.com/preferences)  allows you to change the country in which you perform the search (or search by the location where you are) and change the language. I am fine with the results either in Italian or in English. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a quick way to toggle between search in USA and search in Italy with one click or combination of keys? Is there maybe a chrome extension that allows that?
2. When I select the language for the results in the Google Preferences ("Currently showing search results in"), is there any impact if I select both Italian and English, versus selecting only Italian when I search for pages in Italy? That is only the language the original page is written in, correct? So, I guess that  if I pick both Italian and English and if there are some pages in the Italian domain that are written in English they will populate the results as well, nothing more nothing less. I am asking this second question to understand if this toggle should change also the language or only the country. I guess I can keep Italian and English both ticked off and just toggle the country.

Comment: You could keep open separate browsers with each search setting. Since Google likely uses cookies that would be overwritten if the browsers were running from the same profile, you would also need separate profiles, or different browsers (e.g. Fierefox for Chromebook + the native one).

Comment: Hmm... `unurl:.it` - for explicitly iItalian domains. Might be harder to find one as general for English. language sites

Answer (score 1):

[Google Search by Country](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-by-country/flcahjclficidjdglfhgkfmahpgnefkm?hl=en) is close to what you are looking for as it allows to:

> Change Google search results to show only selected country's results.

To use it, you must:

> Enter your search into Google. Once results have been loaded, use the extension's icon/button to select the country you would like the results from